# could not understand this paragraph meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

I could not understand this paragraph meaning.

> He might be out of jail at last, but the emotional taint of his
>   shameful months of captivity clung to him with a tenacity..that no amount of bathing could banish

I am referring to this 
 at last he out of jail. but he in shame of his taint.
But I am not exactly sure which meanings are correct in this context.

Comment: at last is an idiom that means: finally.

Comment: A **taint** is an odor or residue.  But here the word is used metaphorically. It is an **emotional taint** that arises from his shame at being in captivity.  Shame clung to him like an odor or residue that  washing could not remove.

Comment: As a side note, you have to say "he **was** out of jail" and "he **was** in shame of his taint".  Just saying "he out of jail" doesn't include a main verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple words: the guy is ashamed because he was imprisoned for months. He tried to bathe the shame out, but it didn't work. The phrase "emotional taint" is a metaphor representing the feeling of guilt that never really left him. It clung to him with tenacity, which means he couldn't get rid of it.